# Backing up and Restoring Jenkins configuration and Logs

Tags: jenkins, configuration, backup, centos7, restore

Is there an easy way to backup and restore a Jenkins master (config, logs, etc)?

Is it just a case of compressing and decompressing the directory (on Centos7):
`/usr/share/tomcat/.jenkins`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just copy the files on JENKINS_HOME or for a better approach you can use

[thinBackup](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/thinBackup)

With thinBackup you can easily make the backup and restore.

Answer (score 0):

According to the wiki, restoring a complete backup is just a case of [replacing the contents of JENKINS_HOME](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins).